# Changing div onclick value using js

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to pass a string to the onclick value of a div and it's just not working, have tried a million ways of doing it and this is what I have at the moment. I have tried passing different strings, plain text etc.. but nothing seems to be placed in the onclick value.

script:

```
    function openPopup(imgname) {
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('delimg').src = 'imgstore/' + imgname;
      document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = 'location.href=\'nextpage.php\'\;';
    }

    function closePopup() {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

and my div:

```
    <div id="confirm" style="top:220px; left:100px;" class="yesnobutton"  onclick="">
        YES
    </div>
```

I've looked on this site and I can't find a solution anywhere..thanks!

edit (ive moved the script below the div.. still not doing anything :( ):

```
<div id='popup' class='popup' style='display:none'>
<h5>Are you sure you wish delete this ad?</h5>
<div style='height:96px; width:128px; border:1px solid black; top:70px; left:50px; position:absolute;'>
    <img id='delimg' src="" style='max-height:96px; max-width:128px;'>
</div>  
<br>
<div id='confirm' style='top:220px; left:100px;' class='yesnobutton'  onclick=''>
    YES
</div>
<div style='top:220px; right:100px;' class='yesnobutton' onClick='closePopup()'>
    NO
</div>    
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function openPopup(imgname) {
document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('delimg').src = 'imgstore/' + imgname;
document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = 'location.href=\'newurl.html\'\;';

}

function closePopup() {
document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include the complete html?

Comment: Make sure `openPopup` function script is either below the div in HTML or it is in onload of the window.

Comment: Nux it wasn't originally but I have moved it round now. El Kabong, I have included code in entirety above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a function to the onclick attribute.

```
<body>
    <div id="confirm" style="top:220px; left:100px;" class="yesnobutton"  onclick="">
        YES
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('confirm').onclick = function() {
            location.href = 'nextpage.php';
        }
    </script>
</body>
```